# What does this speech recognition error mean in my flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have an error with my flutter app, so basically I have made a speech to text app, and it works on my iOS simulator and device perfectly. But on my android emulator, when I start the speech to text function, it outputs this error:

```
I/flutter ( 4958): onError: SpeechRecognitionError msg: error_permission, permanent: true
```

I am also using this speech to text package:

```
speech_to_text: ^2.3.0
```

Does anyone know what this means? I have also added the requirements in the AndroidManifest.xml, the "RECORD_AUDIO" and "INTERNET" ones. (these were listed on the pub.dev page for this package)

Here is my code:

```
class SpeechScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SpeechScreenState createState() => _SpeechScreenState();
}

class _SpeechScreenState extends State<SpeechScreen> {
  final Map<String, HighlightedWord> _highlights = {
    'Hablas': HighlightedWord(
      onTap: () => print('voice'),
      textStyle: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.green,
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  };

  stt.SpeechToText _speech;
  bool _isListening = false;
  String _text = 'Press the button and start speaking';
  double _confidence = 1.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _speech = stt.SpeechToText();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Speech To Text'),
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
      floatingActionButton: AvatarGlow(
        animate: _isListening,
        glowColor: Colors.red,
        endRadius: 75.0,
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
        repeatPauseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        repeat: true,
        child: RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: _listen,
            child: Icon(
              _isListening ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_none,
              size: 32,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            fillColor: Colors.red,
            elevation: 2.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(64, 64)),
            splashColor: Colors.red),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        reverse: true,
        child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 30.0, 30.0, 150.0),
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'AI Confidence Level: ${(_confidence * 100.0).toStringAsFixed(1)}%',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 32.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                TextHighlight(
                  text: _text,
                  words: _highlights,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _listen() async {
    if (!_isListening) {
      bool available = await _speech.initialize(
        onStatus: (val) => print('onStatus: $val'),
        onError: (val) => print('onError: $val'),
      );
      if (available) {
        setState(() => _isListening = true);
        _speech.listen(
          onResult: (val) => setState(() {
            _text = val.recognizedWords;
            if (val.hasConfidenceRating && val.confidence > 0) {
              _confidence = val.confidence;
            }
          }),
        );
      }
    } else {
      setState(() => _isListening = false);
      _speech.stop();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It Doesn't work on android because you didn't give it the permissions to Record Audio. Navigate to this file:

```
<project root>/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
```

and add these two lines to it

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

at the end it should look something like this:
[image]

Comment: yeah i did this... still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what error do you get? Still the same? If yes could you send me your manifest file?
PS: Be sure that you wrote it into the Manifest file inside the main folder and not the debug folder. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: yeah sure, mind if i send it on discord??

Comment: Nope just send it : )